Closed form for $ \sum_{a_1=0}^\infty~\sum_{a_2=0}^\infty~\cdots~\sum_{a_n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{(a_1!+a_2!+\ldots+a_n!)} $
After reading this post and the general solution for that case, I wonder if there is a closed form for the general solution for this sum:
$ \sum_{a_1=0}^\infty~\sum_{a_2=0}^\infty~\cdots~\sum_{a_n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{(a_1!+a_2!+\ldots+a_n!)}
$
Any idea?

Did you have any reason to believe that there exists a closed form? This site is not for posting wild conjectures.

If you post this on MathOverflow, they might explain why it's so hard. For now, here's a taste of why. We can equivalently restate this as $\int_0^1\frac{f^n}{x}dx$ with $f=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{i!}$. Even numerically, it's hard enough to understand $f$, let alone evaluate such integrals.

@jjagmath I Just wondered after reading the original post

@J.G. thank you for your kind explany, I'll surely do

Also posted to MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/471421/closed-form-for-sum-a-1-0-infty-sum-a-2-0-infty-cdots-sum-a-n-0-i
